# UITextView as tableFooterView in UITableView - weird table scrolling behavior

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, uitextview

I have a simple UITableView which includes an instance of UITextView set as the tableFooterView. The table is editable and the idea is that a longer comment can also be entered into the UITextView if the table is being edited.

In setEditing editing of the textview is switched on or off by setting

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
  textview.editable = editing; 
}
```

among other things obviously.

The weird part is that upon enabling editing of the textview for the first time (the initial state is editable=NO), the UITableView actually scrolls down to the top of the footer (i.e. the top of the UITextView).

How can I prevent this from happening?

**Edit:** 
I noticed that this only happens if there is no text assigned to the UITextView previously, i.e. when it's empty.